# When an html select/option changes an input field needs to be updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my rails application I have a select tag generated from a model(A user can select different countries). I would like to update the value of a text_field (for a country telephone code) that can be found on the same view when the user selects a different option. I need to extract the value (country_code) that needs to be placed in the text_field from a model and based on the option (country) the user selected. I have tried to go about this a few different ways but I seem to get stuck. Please help.

```
View:
     <%= f.label :country %>
     <%= select("user", :country, Country.all.collect{ |c| c[0] }, {prompt: "-- Select Country --"} )%>

     <%= f.text_field :country_code, size: 4, readonly: true %>
```

I can get the country code based on the country name.

```
country_code = Country.find_country_by_name('united states').country_code
```

**Update:**
I tried to use the following javascript but I am not sure how to extract the value that I am looking for:

```
Javascript:
   $ -> 
   $("select#user_country").change -> 
    $("input#user_country_code").val( MISSING VALUE )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using javascript. Create a function that binds to when the select field changes. Then create an API call in your app that will respond with the changes you want to make to the form.

Comment: I tried to implement that but I failed in trying to get the country_code out and placing it in the the text_field. I will update my question to be more specific.

Comment: try something like this
var country_code = $('#country_code').val(); ......
$('#text_field').val(country_code);

Answer (score 1):

you have an extra right curly bracket ( } ) on your selector. Not sure about the syntax of coffee script I think.

```
$("select#user_country}")
```